# How to learn Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: self-learning

I would like to become a good Libreoffice Calc user. How should I learn to use it, as I don't have any real business cases to solve but I would like to learn those? I have studied a good skills on Python and a very basics of R. I don't want to spend money more than 100 € for learning.

Comment: Define what it requires to be a good user. When you've defined it, notice that you also have created a todo list on what to learn.

Comment: It is unclear why you're mentioning Python and R. What is your intention with Calc? Given the mentions of Python and R, I infer you're not just trying to put some data in a tabular format.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to answer since you have no stated goal, so we need to speak in generalities.  To learn LibreOffice Calc, you can:

- Explore the interface and familiarize yourself with the different features and tools, like entering data, creating formulas, formatting cells, creating charts, filtering and sorting, and pivot tables.
- Read through official documentation and user guides.
- There are plenty of tutorials available on the LibreOffice website and on YouTube.
- Create some practice projects for yourself.  Here are some challenges you might consider: https://ryanstutorials.net/programming-challenges/spreadsheet-challenges.php or https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Spreadsheets/Spreadsheet_challenges

Good luck!